# Continuously differentiable functions dense in $L^2[a,b]$

Tags: metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral

I read in Kolmgorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* (p. 408 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that the set of continuously differentiable functions are dense everywhere in space $L^1[a,b]$ of Lebesgue integrable functions on $[a,b]$ endowed with distance $d(f,g)=\int_{[a,b]}|f-g|d\mu$.

I know that the set of continuous functions is dense everywhere in $L^1[a,b]$, but how to prove that the set of continuously differentiable functions is dense everywhere too? I thank you all very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a direct consequence of [Stone-Weierstrass' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Let $f\in L_1[a,b]$, and $\epsilon>0$. You know that there is some $g\in C[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b|f-g|d\mu<\epsilon/2$. Now, let $p$ a polynomial such that $\|p-g\|_\infty<\epsilon/[2(b-a)]$.

Then 
$$\int_a^b|f-p|d\mu\le\int_a^b|f-g|d\mu+\int_a^b|g-p|d\mu<\epsilon$$

Comment: A polynomial! I know Weierstrass theorem from my studies in numerical analysis with a proof based on Bernstein polynomials, fortunately, because Kolmogorov-Fomin's uses the above result precisely to prove Weierstrass theorem, which would be a circular argument. Your very reasoning shows that the sets of functions differentiable $k$ times are everywhere dense. Thank you so much!!!