# Set of fuctions that are differentiable and have their derivative in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is a dense set in $L^2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $S=\{x\in L^2(\mathbb R):\frac{dx}{dt} \text{ exists},\frac{dx}{dt}\in L^2(\mathbb R)\}$.

I want to prove that $S$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$. The norm is the usual $L^2$ norm:
$$
\|x\|_2=\left(\int_\mathbb R |x(t)|^2dt\right)^{1/2}.
$$

I know how to prove this for $L^2[a,b]$ by approximating with polynomials with [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem). A weaker result can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024034/continuously-differentiable-functions-dense-in-l2a-b). But I struggle to play with polynomials in $\mathbb R$, since no non-zero polynomials are in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

**How to prove that $S$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$?** Or can anyone prove a stronger result? It seems there are proper dense subsets of $S$.

Comment: Look into the Schwartz space.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Could you write an answer? I am not familiar with Schwartz space. I am Searching for it online now. I know the definition of it, but don't know how it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, the space of infinitely differentiable, compactly supported functions on $\mathbb R$, is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.  Take any $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, approximate it in the $L^2$-norm by a simple function, and approximate the simple function by something in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, using regularity properties of Lebesgue measure and a $C^\infty$ version of the Urysohn lemma.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain a bit more about how Urysohn Lemma can be used? The lemma states that any two disjoint closed subsets can be separated by a continuous function, but what are the closed sets here?

Comment: You have the approximating simple function $g$.  Fix $\alpha\in g(\mathbb R)$ nonzero, and let $E=g^{-1}(\alpha)$.  By regularity of Lebesgue measure, there exist a compact set $K$ and an open set $U$ such that $K\subset E\subset U$ and the measure of $U\setminus K$ is as small as desired.  Then by (a version of) Urysohn's lemma, there exists a smooth function $\varphi$ such that $\varphi=1$ on $K$ and $\varphi=0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus U$.

Comment: Thank you. Let me do the proof myself